# My slash command handler doesn't work, but there are no errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was adapting my command handler to work with slash and it worked, but now I have other problems

1 - When I try to run the /ping command, "interaction failed" appears and there is no error on the console

2 - I put some console.log() to see if it was delivering the right value, but some variables gave undefined

This is my command handler (`index.js`):

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const pComandos = fs.readdirSync('Comandos');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.description = new Discord.Collection();

for (const folder of pComandos) {
    const file = fs.readdirSync('Comandos/' + folder);

    for (const comando of file) {

        let cmd = require(`./Comandos/${folder}/${comando}`);
        commandsArray = [];

        console.log(chalk.green(`[ C ] O comando ` + chalk.bold(comando) + ` foi carregado!`))

        client.commands.set(cmd.help.name, cmd)
        if (cmd.help.description) {
            cmd.desc = true
            cmd.help.description.forEach(desc => client.commands.set(desc, cmd))
        }
        client.commands.set(cmd)
        commandsArray.push({
            name: cmd.help.name,
            description: cmd.help.description.join("")
          })

        if (cmd.init) cmd.init(client)

        client.on("ready", async() => {
            const server = await client.guilds.cache.get("892210305558532116")
            server.commands.set(commandsArray)
        })
    }
}
```

The interaction event (`interactionCreate.js`):

```js
const { Interaction, CommandInteraction } = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");

exports.run = (client, interaction) => {
  if (interaction.isCommand()) {

    const pComandos = fs.readdirSync('./Comandos');
    for (const folder of pComandos) {
      let file = fs.readdirSync("./Comandos/" + folder);

      console.log(file) // [ 'ping.js' ]

      for (const comando of file) {
        let cmd = require(`../../Comandos/${folder}/${comando}`);

        console.log(cmd)
        /* 
            {
                run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
                help: { name: 'ping', description: [ 'Pong!' ] },
                desc: true
            }
        */

        let command =
          client.commands.get(cmd) ||
          client.commands.get(client.description.get(cmd));

          console.log(command) // undefined
          console.log(client.commands.get(cmd)) // undefined
          
        if (command) {
          command.run(client, interaction);
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

The ping command (`ping.js`):

```js
const discord = require("discord.js");

exports.run = async (client, interaction) => {

  interaction.deferUpdate();
  
  var latencia = Date.now() - interaction.createdTimestamp

  interaction.reply({content: `<:emoji_3:892431734203891722> | Ping atual do client: ${client.ws.ping} (${latencia}).\n | Timezone: ${process.env.TZ}`});

};
exports.help = {
  name: "ping",
  description: ["Pong!"]
};
```

This is my file organization: https://prnt.sc/20ddh4e
And the console (Console.log values ​​are in the interactionCreate.js code): https://prnt.sc/20ddnlv

Answer (score 0):

You should call `interaction.deferReply()` followed by `interaction.editReply(content)`. `interaction.deferUpdate()` is used for updates, not replies.

Comment: Did not work. :/